# Create File encountered operating system error 4350 when running MVC Application

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, windows-7

I have a vanilla MVC 5 application.  When running and logging in I get the following:

> CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 4350(This file is
>   currently not available for use on this computer.) while attempting to
>   open or create the physical file '\fsrsvr06pr\users\medmondson\Visual
>   Studio
>   2015\Projects\Portal\Portal\App_Data\aspnet-Portal-20160805104334.mdf'.
>   CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created.
>   Check related errors.

The file **does** exist:

[image]

Although the file is on a fileshare, which could possibly have an effect.

So:

- Are file shares a problem?
- How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I had problems with client side caching, therefore the problem was at the operating system level.

To resolve I formatted the local database with this command:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\CSC\Parameters" /v FormatDatabase /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

then restarted my machine.

[The Microsoft Support article relating to this.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/942974)